# How do skill-ups work?

Tags: puzzle-and-dragons

Active Skills have levels. How does one level them up? What does levelling them up do?

Most specifically, is it true that "if a monster is Ultimate Evolved, you will get a guaranteed Skill Up when you feed it a monster that's Lv 99 and with the same ID["](http://pad.wikia.com/wiki/Monster_Skills#100.25_Skill_Up)? Those are suspiciously specific conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Active skills each have their own charge time as well, corresponding to a countdown which lets you use the skill when it hits zero.  There are three ways to reduce the countdown:

- Inside the dungeon, match at least one set of orbs.  The set you match doesn't need to do any damage, and even matching jammer or poison orbs still advances the countdown.  This, of course, means you must survive for that many turns before you can use the skill.
- Some monsters have a Skill Boost awakening which starts your entire team with the countdown reduced by one turn.  This does stack, and some have multiple of these awakenings.
- Most monsters can have their skills leveled up, which means that the initial countdown value is lowered from its default value.

Combining the second and third ways, it is entirely possible to start a dungeon with some skills available for immediate use.  So that's *what* it does.  As for *how* it's done, you can either

- Fuse a monster with the same active skill in Power-Up Fusion.  Having the same effect isn't enough; it must have the same name as well.  For example, a [Hobgoblin](http://www.puzzledragonx.com/en/monster.asp?n=61) won't skill up a [Shu](http://www.puzzledragonx.com/en/monster.asp?n=1871).  **Note that, by default, this only occurs with a 10% chance.  There are often events which double the rate to 20%, but this method is still by no means guaranteed.**
- Or, you can do what you mentioned and feed a monster an identical copy of itself at lvl 99.  They must be an ultimate evolution, so feeding a lvl 99 [Firedragon Tyrannos](http://www.puzzledragonx.com/en/monster.asp?n=4) will not work.  [This has been stated officially by GungHo](https://www.facebook.com/notes/puzzle-dragons-north-america-gungho/721-patch-notes/944326888929237), and is mainly meant as a way to *guarantee* skill ups for monsters which are otherwise difficult to get or require magic stones.

Hope that helps!